# What could cause random errors to occur in php parsing?

Tags: php, apache2

Sorry that the context is so vague but this problem is very vague. I will try to convey the experience so far.

This is the code I am editing and it is on line 133:

```
$log->log('info', 'total_data: ' . count( $result->data ) );
```

The above code worked, when I changed the string to 'total_results' it caused a syntax error:

```
$log->log('info', 'total_results: ' . count( $result->data ) );
```

The error randomly changes whenever any characters change. For example the above code made this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']' in /web/api.php on line 180
```

FYI: there are only 179 lines in this file.

If I remove one letter from the string:

```
$log->log('info', 'total_result: ' . count( $result->data ) );
```

The above error changes to:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']' in /web/api.php on line 181
```

If I keep removing one letter at a time and refreshing the line number keeps incrementing.

Sometimes if I delete the line, save, refresh, paste it back in, save, refresh it will then work. Sometimes if I add more characters to the string it will work. This must be something on a level beyond syntax errors because the same code will work at a later time. I have tried to restart apache2 but that does not fix anything, it usually displays a different random error. I cannot see any consistency with the error messages. The one consistent thing seems to be that as long as nothing changes the error will stay the same.

Here are other error messages I have seen while trying to find some consistencies:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'DirectMap4k' (T_STRING) in /web/api.php on line 180
```

Again I deleted one line, saved, refreshed, put that line back, saved, refreshed and then it worked.

logging.php

```
<?php

class logger {
protected $file     = null;
protected $log_level    = 3;
protected $_date_fmt    = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
protected $_levels      = [ 'CRITICAL'  => 0,
                    'ERROR' => 1,
                    'WARNING'   => 2,
                    'INFO'  => 3,
                    'DEBUG' => 4,
                    'TRACE' => 5,
                    'TRACE1'    => 6,
                    'TRACE2'    => 7 ];

function __construct( $name = 'Anonymous',
              $file = 'application.log' )
{
    $this->name     = $name;
    $this->filename     = $file;

    // check if file exists before fopen creates the file
    $new_file       = ! file_exists( $file );

    // die if file is not writable
    if( ! ( $new_file or is_writable( $file ) )) {
    die( "logger class cannot write to file: <b>" . $file . "</b>" );
    }
    $this->file     = fopen( $file, 'a' );

    if( $new_file ) {
    $this->write( "<"."?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?".">\n\n" );
    }
}

public function log( $level, $message )
{
    if( $this->_levels[ strtoupper( $level ) ] > $this->log_level ) {
    // do not log
    return;
    }

    list( $usec, $sec ) = explode( ' ', microtime() );
    $datetime       = sprintf( '%s.%03d',
                   date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $sec),
                   floor($usec * 1000) );

    $write      = sprintf( '%s - %8.8s : %s',
                   $datetime,
                   strtolower( $level ),
                   $message );
    $this->write( $write . "\n" );
}

private function write( $message )
{
    fwrite( $this->file, $message );
}

function __destruct()
{
    if( $this->file ) {
    fclose( $this->file );
    }
}

}

?>
```

Comment: The code you posted shouldn't cause any errors. It doesn't even contain any `]` characters. Can you post more code (from the lines above it)?

Comment: Is your log command *in* /web/api.php ?

Comment: There is quite a lot of code in several included files. There error that is being displayed is 100% inaccurate for several reasons. I'm wondering what I can do to discover this bug. I would have thought something this inconsistent would have to do with file caching but my apache2 cache mod is disabled.

Comment: What is the logging library you are using?

Comment: I simple custom class using fopen, fwrite

Comment: I see, sorry...assumed you were using [PEAR logging](http://pear.php.net/package/Log/docs/latest/Log/Log.html#methodlog).

Comment: Can you post that log function?

Comment: Do you FTP those files up from your local environment?

Comment: I have posted the logging.php code. I ssh into the server and my editor is Emacs.

Comment: Adding the PHP closing tag at the end of that file has made the problem go away. Still don't know what the bug is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being with Vagrant file synching using HGFS.  The files are actually on the host machine and they were not being accurately synchronized.  To avoid the random errors, I have resorted to never sharing development code over HGFS.